# How to use width in bootstrap and css properly Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, width, react-bootstrap

I am using this code with react-bootstrap and css:

```
<div className="justify-content-center d-flex">
              <Form>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                  <Form.Control
                    className="width-400"
                    placeholder="E-mail"
                    onChange={this.emailHandler}
                  />
                  {this.state.emailInvalid ? (
                    <span className="text-danger">
                      Por favor digite um e-mail válido
                    </span>
                  ) : null}
                </Form.Group>
                <div>
                  {this.state.spinner ? (
                    <Spinner animation="border" variant="success" />
                  ) : (
                    <Button
                      className="mb-3 width-400"
                      onClick={this.sendRecoveryEmail}
                      variant="success"
                    >
                      Recuperar
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </Form>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.width-400 {
  width: 400px;
}
```

So I have an variable(spinner) that is a boolean, when is false a button renders and when the button is pressed the spinner is redered.
When the button is on, the form-control use the right width size and renders with 400px.

[image: form control with button]

But when the spinner is on the form-control get the bootstrap default and resizes to 100%.

[image: form control with spinner]

I can click on the checkbox and unselect and the right width size works fine, or I can use !important in the css, but I know that this is not a good anwser.
So what am I missing here?

Comment: Set the width on the container - not on each individual element. You'll have better luck.

Comment: I use in the form group and it works fine. But what I want to know is that when the button is on the input keep the size and when the button dissapear the size is reduced and doens´t get the size that I put on that class

Comment: "_I use in the form group and it works fine._" - The only style on the form.group is a bottom margin. But, this is an interesting problem. Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this behavior.